# Converting existing spring project to use roo help

Tags: java, hibernate, upgrade, spring-roo

I have a project that uses really good spring best practices already. It uses freemarker though instead of JSP, and I am sure my controller actions are going to be much different than the ones that roo generates. It's rest-based still, but my naming conventions of methods are very different by the looks of things. Mine look a lot more like rails/grails.

I also used Hibernate directly - not JPA. The project has been around since 2009, and at the time, I honestly liked the XML mappings a lot more than the JPA annotations.

Anyway, I was curious if I could upgrade this project to use ROO, or if I should stay clear of it. Can anyone offer tips/suggestions/guidance - even if that advice is to simply stay away?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there is the only way to switch your project to use Roo — build it from scratch using Roo. Maybe with reverse engineering of your DB. But I suppose it is not proper way for you. So I can give you the only advise — wait for the next project and build it with Roo from scratch (if you still want to give it a try).